# Load database from remote hosted server : phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have offline version of a project and the same project updated online with large records of database , I want to access the database hosted on the server from the local host  and my trials to do that:

**No 1:**

```
<?php

// mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
// mysql_select_db('eghtml5_XXXX');
$dbserver="http://96.127.132.74:xxxx";


$username="xxxxx";
$password="xxxxx";

// $username="root";
// $password="";
$dbname="database_name";
$connection=mysql_connect("$dbserver","$username","$password")or die("could not     connect to the server");

mysql_select_db($dbname, $connection) or die("Error here");
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8;");

mysql_query("SET CHARACTER_SET utf8;");
?>
```

and another trial to append this configuration at php.ini  at the local host

```
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']          = '96.127.132.74';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port']          = 'XXXX';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket']        = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type']  = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension']     = 'mysql';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress']      = FALSE;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']     = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']          = 'xxxx';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']      = 'ْْxxxx';
```

both ways haven't worked with me !

Comment: both approach won't work if your MySQL server don't allow remote connection (most probably it won't in production servers).

Comment: thanks But how to check if the server allow /doesn't  allow for remote connections !

Comment: just telnet to port 3306. `telnet serverIP 3306` if you get connected your mysql server allows remote connection. BTW what OS are you using? If you are not able to connect directly you  can always use SSH tunnel, if SSH connection is available(normally available in production server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the user you are trying to logon with is allowed to connect from locations that are not "localhost" or the IP of the online server.

And you'll have to check if port 3306 (MySQL STD Port) is open to connect from outside (might be a security issue)

Comment: Many thanks for your answer , But How to do this double check , I open the hosted database ->settings I can't find any tabs or options to do that !

Comment: You can check the port with http://ping.eu/port-chk/ just enter the IP and Port 3306 (if the port is closed you don't have to check the user.

Comment: there is much easier way to check if you don't have or don't know to use `telnet` is just use any browser to your `server:3306`. like `http://your.mysql.serverIP:3306` you will get some junk displayed it the port is open.